# How to send data to socket.io from react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I've never used Socket.IO before so this is very new for me.

I have a taxi app in react which will send a new order as an event through Socket.IO but I don't see any error or response.

Server Side it looks like this:

```
client.on('newOrder', function(data){
    socketController.newOrder(data, io, client);
});

newOrder: function(data, io, client) {
    order.create(data, io, client, function(response){});       
}

Order.prototype.create = function (data, io, client, callback) {

    console.log("ORDER DATA = " + JSON.stringify(data));

    let luggage = 0;
    if (typeof data.luggage !== 'undefined')
        luggage = data.luggage;

    let insertData = {
        client_id: data.id_client,
        start_address: data.origin.name,
        start_lat: data.origin.latitude,
        start_lng: data.origin.longitude,
        end_address: data.destination.name,
        end_lat: data.destination.latitude,
        end_lng: data.destination.longitude,
        options: JSON.stringify(data.options),
        car_options: JSON.stringify(data.car_options),
        car_type: data.car_type,
        passengers: data.passengers,
        luggage: luggage,
        payment_method: data.payment_method,
        profile_id: data.profile,
        profile_type: data.profile_type
    };

    if (data.schedule_time != null && data.schedule_time.length > 0) {
        insertData.schedule_time = data.schedule_time
    }

    db.query("INSERT INTO orders SET ?", insertData,
        function (err, results, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Order.create [ERROR: " + err + "]");
                return callback({ error: true, message: err });
            }

            data.id_order = results.insertId;

            const timeInsert = {
                order_id: data.id_order,
                new: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
            };

            db.query("INSERT INTO orders_timestamps SET ?", timeInsert, function (err, results, fields) { });

            client.emit("orderSaved", { "id_order": data.id_order });
            getOrder(data.id_order, function (order) {

                sendOrdersToDriver(data, order, io, function (data) {
                    console.log("Order.create [SUCCESS]");
                    return callback(data);
                });
            });


        }
    );

};
```

Client Side it looks like this

```
const data = {
    id_client: user.id,
    car_type: "executive",
    car_options: [],
    passengers: 1,
    luggage: 2,
    payment_method: "cash",
    options: [],
    origin: { name: pickUp, latitude: pickUpCoordinates.lat, longitude: pickUpCoordinates.lng },
    destination: { name: dropOff, latitude: dropOffCoordinates.lat, longitude: dropOffCoordinates.lng },
    schedule_time: new Date(),
    profile: "",
    profile_type: "owner"
}
socket.emit("newOrder", data, function (response) {
    console.log('emit response', response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit 1:
Let me try to explain how does this callback stuff working,

```js
// here we are at the client-side
// so here from client side i'm sending a data and a callback
// socket.emit('event-name', data, callback); signature
socket.emit('some-event', { a: true }, function(dataFromServer) {
    console.log(dataFromServer);
});
```

```js
// here we are at server-side
socket.on('some-event', function(data, callback) {
    // we are getting the data first argument and callback second
    // let's say we are testing if data has a === true;
    if(data.a) { // same as data.a === true
       // here we are gonna send 'hi' to callback
       return callback('hi the data was valid for me');
    }
    // otherwise we are assuming that data wasn't valid
    return callback('your data is not okey mate!');
});
```

So from client-side if you send a data contains `{ a: true }` as prop you should see that callback consoling `'hi the data was valid for me'` this.

Otherwise if it doesn't contain `a` or `a: false` then you should see `'your data is not okey mate!'` from your client's callback.

Consedering this senario; go for your code and check =)

First please check if you `socket.connected === true` on your frontend.

Second here you are sending `data` and a `callback` through your `emit`

```js
socket.emit("newOrder", data, /*this is your callback*/function (response) {
    console.log('emit response', response);
});
```

And here on your server you are only getting data from client.

```js
// needs to be like this
client.on('newOrder', function(data, callback) {
    socketController.newOrder(data, callback, io, client);
});
// same with 
newOrder: function(data, callback, io, client) {
     // you probably dont need to send this empty callback cause actualy callback 
     // coming after `data`, `callback`
    order.create(data, callback, io, client); //function(response){});       
}

// same with 
Order.prototype.create = function (data callback, io, client) {
...

  sendOrdersToDriver(data, order, io, function (data) {
    console.log("Order.create [SUCCESS]");
    // here you are calling it so it needs to work if
    // your `sendOrdersToDriver` function actually calls it's 
    // own callback?
    return callback(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: I've checked and `socket.connected` is `true`. Now from your second point I should not send date through `emit`?

Comment: What do you mean by `date`?

Comment: https://github.com/halilcakar/socketio-emit-callback-example clone this example and look at code i made a small example for you

Comment: `data` not `date` sorry for typo

Comment: Yea if you need to send something from client to server ofc you can, above it's also sending a `data`

Comment: So the idea is that the backend is working fine with the mobile apps which are developed by someone else and I don't have access on code. Now I am building something on web using that backend. What it supposed to do is to get that data and create a new object on DB. But from my side this doesn't do anything. So I was interested to know if I am doing something wrong

Comment: The only wrong u have made is fron your server-side you didn't accept the callback as an arguments to `client.on` event. other's seems to be fine. if you can't chage the order of objects, cause you can't see 'mobile' version of code, then add the callback to the end

Comment: It is not working even if I use it like this `socket.emit("newOrder", data)`

Comment: just look the example i sended on here github.com/halilcakar/socketio-emit-callback-example this sends data + callback together in simplest way possible